# Flutter Gestures: Conflict of panable view and dragable item

Tags: flutter, gesture, drag, gesturedetector, pan

**TDLR**

How can I setup a scrollable view (two-finger) with a draggable item (one-finger) in Flutter in way that the item doesn't eat up the two-finger gesture.

**Goal**

I am trying to setup an application in Flutter that behaves as follows:

- It provides a view that can be panned and zoomed with two finger gestures
- Inside view resides an item (e.g. box) that can be dragged with one finger

At the moment I am using GestureDetectors for that. I am aware of the GestureArena handling that Flutter internally does.

[image]

**Problem**

When panning the view with two fingers, the item interprets this as a drag operation once at least one finger touches the item. Technically spoken "onHorizontalDragUpdate" is called although I am using two fingers on the screen.

The GestureArea debug output states that the Drag-GestureDetector of the item wins:

```
Accepting: HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer#b044d(debugOwner: GestureDetector-[GlobalKey#ebeb1 Grüne Box], start behavior: start)
```

What I'd like to have is that the Scale-GestureDetector of the view wins.

What I would expect for that is that either the HorizontalDrag-GestureDetector on the item surrenders in the gesture arena once a second finger comes into play. Or that the Scale-GestureDetector on the view declares victory in the arena once two fingers are used.

**Question**

How can this use case be solved in Flutter?

- Is it possible to configure the Drag-GestureDetector to only accept one finger drags?
- Or is it possible to give the Scale-GestureDetector priority for two finger touches?
- Or is there any other solution?

This use case sounds so common that I probably just didn't find the answer yet, although it is probably there. Thus I really appreciate any help.

**Example**

The following video demonstrates the problem. The two finger pan should always pan the view and not scale the green box. The video is made in the Android emulator:

https://www.screencast.com/t/Y6nwpioFb

Here is the full source code of that sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  debugPrintGestureArenaDiagnostics = true;
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _scale = 1.0;
  var _translation = const Offset(0, 0);
  double _scaleStart = 1.0;
  double _boxScale = 1.0;
  final _color = Colors.green;
  final _boxGesture = GlobalKey(debugLabel: "Grüne Box");
  final _viewGesture = GlobalKey(debugLabel: "Blaue View");

  void _handleDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      if (details.delta.distance > 0) {
        _boxScale = _boxScale + (details.delta.dx / 100);
      }
    });
  }

  Widget buildContent(BuildContext context) {
    Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.identity();
    matrix.scale(_scale);
    matrix.translate(_translation.dx, _translation.dy);

    // Scalable item
    Widget child = Transform(
      transform: matrix,
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: GestureDetector(
        key: _boxGesture,
        onHorizontalDragUpdate: _handleDragUpdate,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 500 * _boxScale,
          height: 500,
          child: Card(
            color: _color,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    child = OverflowBox(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      minWidth: 0.0,
      minHeight: 0.0,
      maxWidth: double.infinity,
      maxHeight: double.infinity,
      child: child,
    );

    child = Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: ClipRect(
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        child: child,
      ),
    );

    // View pan/zoom handling
    child = GestureDetector(
      key: _viewGesture,
      onScaleStart: (details) {
        _scaleStart = _scale;
      },
      onScaleUpdate: (details) {
        if (details.pointerCount == 2) {
          setState(() {
            _scale = _scaleStart * details.scale;
            _translation += details.focalPointDelta;
          });
        }
      },
      onScaleEnd: (details) {},
      child: child,
    );

    child = Center(
      child: child,
    );

    return child;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: buildContent(context),
        ));
  }
}
```